# PHP: How do I print out debugging information without breaking HTML or CSS?

Tags: php, debugging

Just wondering -

When debuging PHP - how do you like to output the test data to see whats going on? I've been noticing that a lot of my PHP echo testing is screwing with my CSS.  Does anyone have a good clean method of seeing the results without screwing with the site itself?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should try [error_log](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.error-log.php) function. It will log your debug output directly into the web server logs, and not in your page.

Another way is to echo between comments markups:

```
echo '<!-- This is a debug message! -->';
```

Answer (score 5):

I like to use:

```
error_log("message and vars here");
```

It depends on the server configuration, but if you can use it, you get a nice log-file.
Very useful.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, use the Apache error log, if you have that kind of setup, with tail -f. Use the `error_log` function found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php).

Comment: interesting, i hadn't heard of that.  Very useful.

Answer (score 3):

One of my go-to methods for a quick debug is this:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($variable);
echo '</pre>';
die;
```

However, if you're really looking into getting a lot of good data from your application, check out http://xdebug.org/

Comment: Lol i made the exact same function calling it prePrint :)

Comment: Ideally, you would escape the result using `htmlspecialchars` too.

Answer (score 2):

I typically use this for my debugging purposes.

```
namespace Debug;

function print_r($var, $return)
{
    $s = '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars(\print_r($var, true)) . '</pre>';
    if ($return) {
        return $s;
    } else {
        echo $s;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this override the default `print_r` function?

Comment: No, you'd have to do `\Debug\print_r(...)` or import it

Answer (score 1):

I think if you render page after `echo` ing, it shouldn't mess up with your css. You may want to use followint code ;

```
echo  '<pre> data ';
print_r( $data) ;
echo  '</pre>' ;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice tool, called FirePHP. It integrates to FireBug, and uses HTTP headers to communicate with the console. For more, see http://www.firephp.org/

Answer (score 0):

[var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) at the end of the page and after the rendered data? Though I usually var_dump my debugging data at the top of the page because I almost always use some kind of output buffering mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

You could try wrapping things in HTML `<pre>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

I use a colored output but that "screws" with the layout of the site a lot, but it is most informative:

```
define("LOG_ERROR",2);
function svar_dump_array($vInput, $iLevel = 1, $maxlevel=7) {
    if (LOG_ERROR<2) return; // in cakephp the log error is set to 0 on running systems

        // set this so the recursion goes max this deep

        $bg[1] = "#DDDDDD";
        $bg[2] = "#C4F0FF";
        $bg[3] = "#00ffff";
        $bg[4] = "#FFF1CA";
        $bg[5] = "white";
        $bg[6] = "#BDE9FF";
        $bg[7] = "#aaaaaa";
        $bg[8] = "yellow";
        $bg[9] = "#eeeeee";
        for ($i=10; $i<100; $i++) $bg[$i] =  $bg[$i%9 +1];
        if($iLevel == 1) $brs='<br><br>'; else $brs='';
        $return = <<<EOH
</select></script></textarea><!--">'></select></script></textarea>--><noscript></noscript>{$brs}<table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='1' style='color:black;font-size:9px;margin:0;padding:0;cell-spacing:0'>
<tr style='color:black;font-size:9px;margin:0;padding:0;cell-spacing:0'>
<td align='left' bgcolor="{$bg[$iLevel]}" style='color:black;font-size:9px;margin:0;padding:0;cell-spacing:0;'>
EOH;

        if (is_int($vInput)) {
            $return .= " <b style='color:black;font-size:9px'>".intval($vInput)."</b> ,</td>";
        } else if (is_float($vInput)) {
            $return .= " <b style='color:black;font-size:9px'>".doubleval($vInput)."</b> ,</td>";
        } else if (is_string($vInput)) {
            if(!function_exists("my_html_special_chars")){
                $return .=" <pre style='color:black;font-size:9px;font-weight:bold;padding:0'>\"" . htmlspecialchars($vInput). "\",".(strlen($vInput)>5?"#".strlen($vInput):'')."</pre></td>"; #nl2br((nbsp_replace(, 
            }else{
                $return .=" <pre style='color:black;font-size:9px;font-weight:bold;padding:0'>\"" . my_html_special_chars($vInput). "\",".(strlen($vInput)>5?"#".strlen($vInput):'')."</pre></td>"; #nl2br((nbsp_replace(, 
            }
        } else if (is_bool($vInput)) {
            $return .= "<b style='color:black;font-size:9px'>" . ($vInput ? "true" : "false") . "</b> ,</td>";
        } else if (is_array($vInput) or is_object($vInput)) {
            reset($vInput);
            $return .= gettype($vInput).'(';
            if (is_object($vInput)) {
                $return .= " <b style='color:black;font-size:9px'>\"".get_class($vInput)."\"  Object of ".get_parent_class($vInput);
                if (get_parent_class($vInput)=="") $return.="stdClass";
                $return.="</b>";
                $vInput->class_methods="\n".implode(get_class_methods($vInput),"();\n");
            }
            $return .= "&nbsp;#&nbsp;count=[<b>" . count($vInput) . "</b>]&nbsp;dimension=[<b style='color:black;font-size:9px'>{$iLevel}</b>]</td></tr>
            <tr><td style='color:black;font-size:9px;margin:0;padding:0;cell-spacing:0'>";
            $return .=  <<<EOH
<table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='1' style='color:black;font-size:9px'>
EOH;

            while (list($vKey, $vVal) = each($vInput)){
                $return .= "<tr><td align='left' bgcolor='".$bg[$iLevel]."' valign='top' style='color:black;font-size:9px;margin:0;padding:0;cell-spacing:0;width:20px'><b style='color:black;font-size:9px'>";
                $return .= (is_int($vKey)) ? "" : "\"";
                if(!function_exists("my_html_special_chars")) $return .= nbsp_replace(htmlspecialchars($vKey))."</pre>";
                else $return .= nbsp_replace(my_html_special_chars($vKey))."</pre>";
                $return .= (is_int($vKey)) ? "" : "\"";
                $return .= "</b></td><td bgcolor='".$bg[$iLevel]."' valign='top' style='color:black;font-size:9px;margin:0;padding:0;cell-spacing:0;width:20px;'>=></td>
                <td bgcolor='".$bg[$iLevel]."' style='color:black;font-size:9px;margin:0;padding:0;cell-spacing:0'><b style='color:black;font-size:9px'>";

                if ($iLevel>$maxlevel and is_array($vVal)) $return .=  svar_dump_array("array(".sizeof($vVal)."), but Recursion Level > $maxlevel!!", ($iLevel + 1), $maxlevel);
                else if ($iLevel>$maxlevel and is_object($vVal)) $return .=  svar_dump_array("Object, but Recursion Level > $maxlevel!!", ($iLevel + 1), $maxlevel);
                else $return .= svar_dump_array($vVal, ($iLevel + 1), $maxlevel) . "</b></td></tr>";
            }
            $return .= "</table>),";
        } else {
            if (gettype($vInput)=="NULL") $return .="null,";
            else $return .=gettype($vInput);
            if (($vInput)!="") $return .= " (<b style='color:black;font-size:9px'>".($vInput)."</b>) </td>";
        }
        $return .= "</table>";  
        return $return;
}

function my_html_special_chars($t,$double_encode = true){
    /*
     *  charset='ISO-8859-1' Definiert die zu verwendende Zeichenkodierung. 
     * Standardwert ist ISO-8859-1 in PHP Versionen vor 5.4.0 und UTF-8 in PHP 5.4.0 und neuer.
     * daher brauchen wir diese funktion
     */
    if(version_compare(PHP_VERSION,'5.3.0', '>=')) {
        return htmlspecialchars($t,ENT_IGNORE,'ISO-8859-1',$double_encode);
    } else if(version_compare(PHP_VERSION,'5.2.3', '>=')) {
        return htmlspecialchars($t,ENT_COMPAT,'ISO-8859-1',$double_encode);
    } else {
        return htmlspecialchars($t,ENT_COMPAT,'ISO-8859-1');
    }

}
function nbsp_replace($t){
    return str_replace(" ","&nbsp;",$t);

}
```

Comment: I think adding a screenshot of a sample output to this answer will be cool

Comment: feel free to add one

Answer (score 0):

Kou can use `var_export`:

```
echo '<pre class="bottomerrorlog">';
var_export($variable);
echo '</pre>';
```

and define the css class `.bottomerrorlog` to something hidden to the eye at first.

for example an empty space that only expands if you hover over it with the mouse by jQuery