# bootstrap fileinput php upload integration

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, file-io

iam trying to get this sample working for me.

http://webtips.krajee.com/ajax-based-file-uploads-using-fileinput-plugin/

Pictures will be shown, but i get only the response "internal error" for every picture (no further information) and no files are uploaded.

index.html

```
<input id="images" name="images[]" type="file" multiple=true class="file-loading">    

<script> 
var $input = $("#images");
$input.fileinput({
uploadUrl: "upload.php",
uploadAsync: false,
showUpload: false, 
showRemove: false, 
minFileCount: 1,
maxFileCount: 5,
overwriteInitial: false,
uploadExtraData: function() {
    return {
        userid: 100,
        username: 'thomas'
    };
}
}).on("filebatchselected", function(event, files) {
$input.fileinput("upload");
});
```

upload.php

```
<?php

if (empty($_FILES['images'])) {
echo json_encode(['error'=>'No files found for upload.']);
return; 
}

$images = $_FILES['images'];
$userid = empty($_POST['userid']) ? '' : $_POST['userid'];
$username = empty($_POST['username']) ? '' : $_POST['username'];

$success = null;
$paths= [];
$filenames = $images['name'];

for($i=0; $i < count($filenames); $i++){
$ext = explode('.', basename($filenames[$i]));
$target = "uploads" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . md5(uniqid()) . "." .    array_pop($ext);
if(move_uploaded_file($images['tmp_name'][$i], $target)) {
    $success = true;
    $paths[] = $target;
} else {
    $success = false;
    break;
}
}

if ($success === true) {
save_data($userid, $username, $paths);

$output = [];
} elseif ($success === false) {
$output = ['error'=>'Error while uploading images. Contact the system administrator'];

foreach ($paths as $file) {
    unlink($file);
}
} else {
$output = ['error'=>'No files were processed.'];
}

echo json_encode($output);

?>
```

Has anyone an idea whats wrong ?

Comment: First try to debug your code, put debug points, check after which point code throwing error. 
Looking at your code and the plugin reference, did you created this `save_data` function?

Comment: dont know what to do with save_data, i simple want to upload the pictures into the folder uploads

Comment: how can i set the debug points ?

Comment: According to the plugin comments, the `save_data` should be used to save the uploaded image information to the database. If you don't want to store data then remove that line and the code should work.

Comment: A simplest way to debug is to put `echo` in your code. reference : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294379/php-debug-echos](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294379/php-debug-echos)

Comment: ok, i uncomment this line, but the same error. 

    //    save_data($userid, $username, $paths);

Comment: Debug your code refer the link I gave you for debugging. You can use this `error_reporting()` of php and see what is the error. Reference : [http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: i didnt find a solution, i think the problem is the json response, i change the upload.php to only these lines, same error: internal server error

    <?php

    $output = "{}": 
    echo json_encode($output);
 
   ?>

Comment: ok, iam a step ahead, it seems to be a config problem of the centos server from my serverhoster, on my ubuntu server now it works, when i found the issue i will post it here ...

Comment: on my ubuntu server with PHP Version 5.5.12-2ubuntu4.1 the upload process works, under the 1&1 Server with PHP Version 5.3.3 not, i try to update the server !